# Autocomplete Bootstrap Typeahead with PHP Ajax dones't work

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a autocomplete with bootstrap, php and ajax.

My php code seems right here's the code:

```
<?php

    $conn = pg_connect("host=y dbname=y user=y");
    $data = array();
    $keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
    $search_param = "{$keyword}%";

    $result = pg_query_params($conn, "select name from users_table where users_table.name like $1", array($search_param));

    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {array_push($data, $row[0]);}

    echo json_encode($data);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

And with a simple test making `$search_param = '%S%';` this is my output from the php file:

```
["Steven","Sally","Sam","Susan"]
```

And this is my index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <label>Search Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Name" />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#name').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"autoComplete.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

I followed this tutorial http://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/dynamic-autocomplete-search-using-bootstrap-typeahead-with-php-ajax.html

but my the autocomplete doesn't work at all and i can understand why. What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should add the json header before the echo: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: ok, then please log out to the console your data on success callback: `console.log(data)`

Comment: Where? (sorry i don't know js i just copied that part from the tutorial)

Comment: before this line: `result($.map(data, function(item)`. Then you should check the console log in your browser

Comment: The error: on POST autoComplete.php  was "The connection used to fetch this resouce was not secure"